# Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\curl_init() Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, curl, lumen, php-curl

```
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com');
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         $response = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
```

I want to run curl call, where I am using above code in Lumen but ending up with

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\curl_init()  error

Do we have to add any thing in namespace?
I have also tried uncomenting the  `extension=curl` in php.ini as well as restarted the server

Comment: Do you have php-curl installed?

Comment: `$ch = \curl_init('http://example.com');` ?

Comment: **Call to undefined function curl_init()**

Comment: Yes @MartinDimitrov I have curl installed same code is working on CodeIgnator framework

Comment: > Please check the namespaces
```namespace App\Http\Controllers;

Comment: if you check the phpinfo() function, can you see curl is really enabled? If it is, we have to dig trough other options, but something is telling me it is not active.

Comment: if you already made configuration, try to restart your local application server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do we have to add any thing in namespace?

nope.

> I have also tried uncomenting the extension=curl

then check your php error log, because the curl extension fails to start for some reason. and since you haven't posted the contents of your error log, nobody here can know why your curl extension fails to load.

(location of the error log is decided by the `error_log` php.ini directive, albeit if you're running php behind a webserver like nginx or apache, then the error log is *usually* just redirected to your webserver's error log. for example with debian/ubuntu nginx+php-fpm, the default error log is nginx's error log at `/var/log/nginx/error.log`)